# Pedir ao usuário para digitar 10 nomes e depois mostrar eles invertidos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Boa noite! Estou tentando resolver essa questão, mas não chego a lugar nenhum. Será que podem me ajudar, por favor?

1} Peça ao usuário para digitar 10 nomes. Exiba na tela todos os nomes digitados, porém de maneira invertida (do último para o primeiro).

O código que estou tentando precisa capturar um id do HTML e mandar o resultado pra lá. Só consegui isso até agora:

```
<script>

    function invert() {

    var nome = [document.getElementById("n1").value, document.getElementById("n2").value, document.getElementById("n3").value, document.getElementById("n4").value, document.getElementById("n5").value, document.getElementById("n6").value, document.getElementById("n7").value, document.getElementById("n8").value, document.getElementById("n9").value, document.getElementById("n10").value]

    var i

    var nomes = ""

    for (i = nome.lenght-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        nomes += nome[i]
    }
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = nomes + ", "
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Não precisa escrever as divs uma por uma, basta aproveitar o laço `for`
- Geralmente a variável `i` é declarada no próprio laço (apenas uma boa prática)
- Use a [função `join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para concatenar os elementos de um array

```js
function invert() {
  const names = [];

  for (let i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
    const name = document.getElementById('n' + i).value;
    names.push(name);
  }

  const divHere = document.getElementById('here');
  divHere.innerHTML = names.join(', ');
}
```